# How to retrieve a record using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to search for a record and display it in a JSP using Spring JDBC.
I am facing the below error now on the browser.

Exception Message:
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlXvC.png)

My JSPs:
Search.jsp:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form action="/SpringMail/searchresults" method="get">
                        <input type="text" name="searchRecord" id="search_record" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter email to search" tabindex="1" required="required">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg search" tabindex="4"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Searchresult.jsp: It has a table. So I am just including the code of that.

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>DisplayName</th>
            <th>DateOfBirth</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
         <th>Contact</th>
         <th>Skills</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
        List students = (List)request.getAttribute("searchresult");
        Iterator stdIter = students.iterator();
        
        while(stdIter.hasNext()) {
            Student s = (Student) stdIter.next();
    %>
        <tr>
            <td><% s.getFirstName(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getLastName(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getDisplayName(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getDateOfBirth(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getEmail(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getPassword(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getContact(); %></td>
            <td><% s.getStudentSkills(); %></td>
        </tr>
    <%  }  %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Controller: RegistrationController:

```
    `   // For Search
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSearchForm() {
    ModelAndView searchmv = new ModelAndView("search");
    return searchmv;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults/{email}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchResults(@PathVariable("email") String email,HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Inside Search method");
    ModelAndView searchResult = new ModelAndView("searchresult");
    request.setAttribute("searchresult", st.getStudent(email));
    return searchResult;
}
// For Search`

getStudent():


    public List<Student> getStudent(String email) {
    System.out.println("Inside getStudent() method");
    System.out.println("Entered email: " + email);
    List studentList = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "select * from student where email = " + email;
    studentList = jt.query(sql, new StudentRowMapper());
    return studentList;
}
```

I am doing this hands on for the first time. Kindly guide me to the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I am getting the search.jsp correctly where I give email in the page to search and retrieve the same record from the DB. But I am getting 404 after clicking enter.

Comment: 404 means that the page does not exist on the server ... check your request mapping urls

Comment: Probably `ViewResolver` can't find your JSP files. Check that they have a exactly the same names as you're using in `ModelAnd`View` and they are in the proper location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
The method: searchResults in RegistrationController is in the wrong format.
I fixed it like this.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchResults(@RequestParam("searchRecord") String email, Map model) {
    ModelAndView searchResult = new ModelAndView("searchresult");
    model.put("searchresult", st.getStudent(email));
    return searchResult;
}
```

Thanks for the inputs